# Seperate columns with space

Tags: r, multiple-columns

```
df<-separate(df$ALISVERIS_TARIHI, c("key","value")," ", extra=merge)
```

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
>   no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"
> ```

[image]

"20190901" how can I separate this into 3 columns like 2019 09 01?

Comment: Did you check the documentation of the `separate` function? It explains how to use it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the 1st column based on number of characters you can use `extract` as -

```
df <- tidyr::extract(df, ALISVERIS_TARIHI, c('year', 'month', 'day'), '(.{4})(..)(..)')
df

#  year month day a
#1 2019    09  01 a
#2 2019    09  08 b
```

The same pattern can be used with `strcapture` in base R -

```
data <- strcapture('(.{4})(..)(..)', df$ALISVERIS_TARIHI, 
           proto = list(year = integer(), month = integer(), day = integer()))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- data.frame(ALISVERIS_TARIHI = c('20190901', '20190908'), a = c('a', 'b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `read.table` from `base R`

```
cbind(read.table(text = as.character(as.Date(df$ALISVERIS_TARIHI,
    format = "%Y%m%d")), sep="-", header = FALSE,
   col.names = c("year", "month", "day")), df['a'])
  year month day a
1 2019     9   1 a
2 2019     9   8 b
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ALISVERIS_TARIHI = c("20190901", "20190908"), 
    a = c("a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```